# status code is 200 but the result value is null

Tags: python, api

I'm using the api 'Stable-Diffusion' with https://stablediffusionapi.com/docs/features/image-to-image.

I wrote the code for request to that api and I got 200 status code. but when I check the body as Postman, it has only null although the api's response has several values.

These are my codes and the messages I requested in Postman. I guessed the reason is why the value in init_image field' is png file. how to change the code "png to str" when post request to api? or any reasons with this?

```
import json
import requests  
import base64
from fastapi import FastAPI 
from pydantic import BaseModel 

app = FastAPI()

# Body content Type
class Request(BaseModel):
    key: str
    prompt: str
    negative_prompt: None
    init_image: str
    width: str
    height: str
    samples: str
    num_inference_steps: str
    guidance_scale: float
    safety_checker: str
    strength: float
    seed: None
    webhook: None
    track_id: None

class Response(BaseModel):        
    status: str
    id: int
    output: list
    meta = {
        "H": int,
        "W": int,
        "enable_attention_slicing": str,
        "file_prefix": str,
        "guidance_scale": float,
        "model": str,
        "n_samples": int,
        "negative_prompt": str,
        "outdir": str, 
        "prompt": str, 
        "revision": str, 
        "safety_checker": None, 
        "seed": int,
        "steps": int,
        "vae": str,
    }

headers = {
    "Authorization": "",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
@app.post("/response")  
def image_to_image(request: Request): 
    print(request)



    url = "https://stablediffusionapi.com/api/v3/img2img"  
    response = requests.post(url, json=request.dict(), headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        try:
            result = Response(**response.json())
            if result.status == "success" and len(result.output) > 0:
                output_image = base64.b64encode(result.output[0].read())
                return output_image
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError, KeyError) as e:
            print(f"Error creating Response object: {e}")
    else:
        return "failed to generate result of images"
```

[image]

What to do for resolving above problem?

Comment: It looks like your image isn't getting passed to the API. You are trying to pass a reference to your local storage that the API cannot access. You would be to host the image somewhere publicly accessible or check if the API supports raw image data streams.

Comment: I'd recommend putting a breakpoint inside the route. Then you can step through the code and see what's actually happening.

Comment: print the content -- return output_image, I think you need to add that bas64 to your response